# internal SATA HDD only seen by Debian after reboot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, sata

---

I am using an old HP Elitedesk 800 G3 with Intel i5-6500 as a headless Debian server with some services using docker compose. I bought a Toshiba Enterprise Capacity 18 TB HDD (MG09ACA18TE) to use as media storage.

Now I am running into problems because the HDD is not recognised by the OS or even the BIOS on first boot after power off. It is not shown in the BIOS boot menu or `lsblk` in debian.

If I reboot one time without power off it suddenly appears and is fully usable. I have added a `nofail` entry in `fstab` to mount it when it is recognised, but I always have to reboot the server one time before I can use it.

I already tried adding a post delay in the BIOS but that didn't help. It also doesn't matter how long the system runs before I reboot. I did not find anything in the system logs but maybe I am not looking for the right things.

How can I start troubleshooting the issue? I dont think the HDD is broken because it works well after the reboot or when I tried it in a USB case. Is there a way to reboot automatically if it isn't recognised as a workaround?

Comment: Sounds as if the drive has trouble spinning up fast enough.

Comment: I thought so too. I forgot to mention I tried to set a POST delay in the BIOS. I tried delaying by 60 seconds and that didn't help. So I don't think it is an issue with how fast the HDD can spin up.

Comment: Could be due to the "power up in standby" feature, although I doubt that is enabled by default on the disk. Does dmesg or syslog show something about that disk?

Comment: @Tapematch, but try listening/feeling if the drive is actually spinning up during this delay.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same situation as @Tapematch. Interestingly enough, it was also with a Toshiba drive, but mine being a 12TB N300.

A slight variation on my side was that the motherboard BIOS *did* show the drive, but as was with the OP, on cold boot Debian did not recognize it (fdisk showed nothing, dmesg listed it as a "DUMMY" entry). Rescanning via scsitools and other methods did nothing. BIOS post delay increases did nothing either, as mentioned by the OP. And as the OP said, it was only on soft reboot did Debian finally see the drive.

The only thing that did work for me was that in the motherboard BIOS (ASUS brand) for each sata port there was an option for "hotswap" which was off by default. I turned it on for the drive in question and bam on cold boot the drive was properly detected by Debian. And this worked consistently each cold boot. Turned it off, and back to square one.

I've never seen this before and so far have only encountered this with a recent Toshiba purchase. A Seagate Ironwolf Pro I bought in tandem did not suffer from this at all.

All motherboard BIOSes may not have this "hotswap" sata option, but I wanted to state what ended up working for me for those that may stumble upon this bizarre situation.